# Как итерировать массив из отдельного файла Angular?

Tags: массивы, angular

Нужна ваша помощь. Я пробую итерировать массив с объектами, которые находятся в другом файле (вместо url endpoint). Я для этого пробую использовать сервис, чтобы вывести на страницу данные и сделать routing.
Однако я получаю ошибку, которая выглядит так:

`TS2345: Argument of type '[{ id: number; post: string; }, { id: number; post: string; }, { id: number; post: string; }, { id: number; post: string; }, { id: number; post: string; }, { id: number; post: string; }, { id: number; post: string; }, { ...; }]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.`

Как получить этот массив и вывести его? Спасибо вам большое

Array.ts

```
export const postsArray = [] = [
   {id: 1, post: '№1'},
   {id: 2, post: '№2'},
   {id: 3, post: '№3'},
]
```

boxService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {postsArray} from "../postArray/arrayPost";
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})

export class BoxService {
constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

getBoxs():Observable<any> {
return this.httpClient.get<any>(postsArray)
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

httpClient.get на вход хочет URL в виде string, а Вы передаете ему свой массив.

Не очень понял чего Вы хотите добиться. Если просто вернуть то, что в postArray, то напишите что-то типа:

```
getBoxs():Observable<any> {
   return of(postsArray)
}
```

и зачем тогда HttpClient?

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает. Дело в том, что пока у меня нет готового backend, я хотел сделать простой массив из элементов (заглушку), чтобы сделать SPA с переходом на отдельную страницу. И вместо того, что вставлять url, я вставляю отдельный файл с массивом, поэтому я и применил httpClient.

Comment: Вы же наверняка используете ng serve. Тогда можете поднять локально proxy для эмуляции backend. Например, как описано тут https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/angular-how-to-proxy-to-backend-server-6fb37ef0d025

Comment: Спасибо большое. Можете пожалуста помочь еще с этим вопросом???: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1399166/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0